# Simple calculator in java - using boolean to ask if user wants to continue

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, calculator

I am writing a basic calculator program in java using JOptionPane. I am very new to this and all the help I have received so far is really appreciated!

My program is suppose to ask users for a number, than has them select the operator to use (+,-,*,/,%) and than asks users for a second number. After all this, the calculation is performed and a result is displayed.

I have working code that loops the calculator so that once the calculation is done, users are asked if they would like to use it again. My code works but what I would like to adjust is that when the user is asked if they want to continue and they say yes, instead of the loop going back and having the input box say "Welcome to the calculator!\nPlease enter your first number:") I'd like it to only say "Please enter your first number:" and than keep going (since the user will not need to be welcomed again).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double numOne; //first number as Float
    double numTwo; //second number as Float
    double result; //result of equation
    String num1; //first number as String
    String num2; //second number as String
    String input; //operator type (+,-,*,/,%)
    boolean useCalculator = false; //False to quit, True to use

    while (!useCalculator) {
        num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome to the calculator!\nPlease enter your first number:");
        numOne = Double.parseDouble(num1);

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you! What would you like to do?\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");
        while (input == null || !(input.equals("+") || input.equals("*") || input.equals("/") || input.equals("-"))) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The operator is invalid. Please select a correct operator.\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");
        }
        num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you!\nPlease enter your second number:");
        numTwo = Double.parseDouble(num2);
    }
}
```

and

```
public static boolean askYesNoQuestion(String prompt) {
    String confirmationInput;
    boolean repeat = false; //false to quite calc, true to repeat use of calc

    while (true) {
        confirmationInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                prompt + " (Please answer yes or no)");

        if (confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            prompt = "Please enter your first number";
            return true;
        } else if (confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have decided to quit the calculator program.\n Goodbye!");
            return false;
        }

        if (!repeat) {
            prompt = "That is an invalid choice. " + prompt;
            repeat = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Same as my other questions, I want to understand and learn how to do this. I have added part of my code for clarity (I can add the whole thing if needed) but what I am really looking for is an explanation on how to accomplish this so I can try it out on my own and work my way through it. I apologize if this is broad, I'd be happy to clear anything up if needed! :)

@ajb
Hi everyone- I have tried removing putting in some changes (adding another while loop and removing the prompts) but I am getting a return error. I have tried to look this up and I am finding it has something to do with my main method using void, but I am unsure how to fix this. If anyone has any further tips on the new code below (so I can again try and work through it), I would really appreciate it!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numOne; //first number as Float
        double numTwo; //second number as Float
        double result; //result of equation
        String num1; //first number as String
        String num2; //second number as String
        String input; //operator type (+,-,*,/,%)
        String confirmationInput;
        boolean useAgain = false;
        boolean useCalculator = false; //false if user decides to quit, true if user continues to use calculator


        while (!useCalculator) {
            num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome to the calculator!\nPlease enter your first number:");
            numOne = Double.parseDouble(num1);

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you! What would you like to do?\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");

            //while loop gathers user input. Asks user repeatedly until a valid operator is entered
            while (input == null || !(input.equals("+") || input.equals("*") || input.equals("/") || input.equals("-") || input.equals("%"))) {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The operator " + input + "  is invalid. Please select a correct operator.\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n%\n/");
            }
            num2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you!\nPlease enter your second number:");
            numTwo = Double.parseDouble(num2);

            //calculates result of user input based on operator choosen
            if (input != null && input.equals("+")) {
                add(numOne, numTwo);
                result = add(numOne, numTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("-")) {
                minus(numOne, numTwo);
                result = minus(numOne, numTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("*")) {
                multiply(numOne, numTwo);
                result = multiply(numOne, numTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("/")) {
                divide(numOne, numTwo);
                result = divide(numOne, numTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("%")) {
                modul(numOne, numTwo);
                result = modul(numOne, numTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numOne + " " + input + " " + numTwo + " is: " + result);
            }

            if (!useCalculator) {
              JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like to continue using this calculator? (Please answer yes or no)");
while (true) {

            if (confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                num1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your first number:");
                return true;
            } else if (confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || confirmationInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have decided to quit the calculator program.\n Goodbye!");
                return false;
            }

            if (!useAgain) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "That is an invalid choice.\nWould you like to continue using this calculator? (Please answer yes or no)");

                useAgain = true;
            }
}
            }


        System.out.println("End of calculator program. Program completed successfully");
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where `askYesNoQuestion()` is actually being called.

Comment: The simplest way to solve the "welcome" question: (1) add `boolean firstTime = true;` before the loop; (2) set `firstTime = false;` inside the loop, just before you loop back; (3) now you can use `firstTime` to control things that should be done only the first time.  For example, you can change the message you display based on whether `firstTime` is true or not.

Comment: A comment about your `askYesNoQuestion` method: Java is pass-by-value.  What this means is that when you set `prompt = "Please enter your first number"` and then return, the statement that sets `prompt` is useless.  That is because you are _only_ setting a local variable that is visible only inside the method; you are not changing anything the caller will see.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that @Tom Biegeleisen! I have it located further down in my code after the program checks for valid input. I have it as:
 if (!useCalculator) {
            useCalculator = !askYesNoQuestion("Would you like to continue using this calculator?");
         }
       }

Sorry, I would modify my original question but I can't seem to find an edit button :)
Thank you ajb, I will definitely try your suggestion- am I understanding correctly that I will not need the askYesNoQuestion then?

Comment: The [edit] button is below your question.

Comment: @ajb , I am still working my way through this but wanted to say thank you for the help!

Comment: Thank you tons everyone- with @ajb 's help I was able to figure it out! Again, I appreciate the support as I work my way through these problems on my own. Have a great day!