# Cannot resolve method error when trying to reproduce the code

Tags: symbols

I know it's been a while since this issue was resolved ( [Simple calculator in java - using boolean to ask if user wants to continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262710/simple-calculator-in-java-using-boolean-to-ask-if-user-wants-to-continue/66437472#66437472) ), but I wanted to recreate this, and when I tried to run it, I got error for all mathematical operators (add, minus, multiply or divide). Error says: "Cannot resolve method 'add'/'minus'/'multiply'/'divide'"

Maybe it would be easier if I add the actual code:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double numberOne;
        double numberTwo;
        double result;
        String number1;
        String number2;
        String input;
        boolean useCalculator = false;

        while (!useCalculator) {
            number1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "This is a calculator\nEnter first number");
            numberOne = Double.parseDouble(number1);

            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n/");

            while (input == null || !(input.equals("+") || input.equals("*") || input.equals("/") || input.equals("-")))
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Thank you! What would you like to do?\nPlease choose from the following options:\n+\n-\n*\n/");
            {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The operator" + input + "is invalid. Please choose a correct one");
            }
            number2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter second number");
            numberTwo = Double.parseDouble(number2);

            if (input != null && input.equals("+")) {
                add(numberOne, numberTwo);
                result = add(numberOne, numberTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numberOne + " " + input + " " + numberTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("-")) {
                minus(numberOne, numberTwo);
                result = minus(numberOne, numberTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numberOne + " " + input + " " + numberTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("*")) {
                multiply(numberOne, numberTwo);
                result = multiply(numberOne, numberTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numberOne + " " + input + " " + numberTwo + " is: " + result);
            } else if (input != null && input.equals("/")) {
                divide(numberOne, numberTwo);
                result = divide(numberOne, numberTwo);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of " + numberOne + " " + input + " " + numberTwo + " is: " + result);
            }


        }

        System.out.println("End of program.");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this and run it without those errors?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You haven't defined any function for `add`, `minus`, `multiply` or `divide`.

Comment: I get that, but I am not sure how to write that? :/

Comment: I somehow managed to get it run without any errors, but now when I press run, nothing happens and I have this message ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50314:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GUI was running in the background, so when I minimized window, I was able to see the calculator and to run it normally.
Message that was displayed in console was reminder about old JDK, so everything is fine now.